# how to create and call an object to be called within a method

Tags: javascript

In the below code, I iterate through the all the directories and any file with extension 'js' i add it to "files_" array.
what I want to do as well is, to create an object or a method "accumulateData" that will be update every time "files_.push" is called. so that, for every iteration, that 
"files_.push" is called, "accumulateData" will contain the recent/updated contants of "files_.push" and the totalsize.

Moreover, I want the below method to return "accumulateData", so that after the method "getFiles" finish iterations i can call something like,

```
console.log(accumulateData.totalSize)
```

please let me know how to achieve that

**code**:

```
function getFiles(dir, files_) {
    files_ = files_ || [];
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);

    for (var i in files) {
        var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
        if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
            getFiles(name, files_);
        } else if (name.endsWith('js')) {
            //totalSize += fs.statSync(name).size;
            files_.push({ name: name, size: fs.statSync(name).size }); 
           /*accumulateData(files, totalSize)
           {
               files = files;
               totoalSize = totalSize;
           }*/
       }
    }
    return files_;
    //return accumulateData
}
```

**my attempts**

```
let totalSize = 0;
let accumulatedData;
function getFiles(dir, files_) {
  files_ = files_ || [];
  const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);

  for (const i in files) {
    const name = dir + '/' + files[i];
    if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) {
      getFiles(name, files_);
    } else if (name.endsWith('js')) {
      // files_.push(name);

      totalSize += fs.statSync(name).size;
      files_.push({ name: name, size: fs.statSync(name).size });
      // data(files, totalSize);

      accumulatedData = {
        files: files,
        totalSize: totalSize
      };
    }
  }
  return accumulatedData;
}

console.log(getFiles('/home/bakria/Projects/smartvehicle').totalSize);
```

Comment: Why don't you push it to another array? Another array which will contain the recent/updated contants of "files_.push" and the totalsize.

Comment: What happens when you need to do additional things to the collection of JS files? Or you need `totalSize` for all image or audio files? Have a function to iterate through the files/directories and gather all files with `fileExtension` passed in as argument. Have separate functions to perform operations on or get data about the resulting collection. Calculating total size of all files in a collection is a task in its own right, and could be made more generic if you separate that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an object that contain both the array of files and the total size:

```
function getFiles(dir, obj) {
    obj = obj || { files: [], totalSize: 0 };                    // if no object is provided then initialize obj with an object that contains an empty array for files and 0 for totalSize
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var name = dir + '/' + files[i];
        var stat = fs.statSync(name);                            // to minimize the calls to fs.statSync
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            getFiles(name, obj);                                 // pass obj to getFile (recursion)
        } else if (name.endsWith('js')) {
            obj.totalSize += stat.size;                          // add this file's size to obj.totalSize
            obj.files.push({ name: name, size: stat.size });     // push this file's object into obj.files
       }
    }
    return obj;                                                  // return obj
}
```

The return will be like this:

```
var result = getFiles("some/dir");
```

where `result` is:

```
{
    files: [/* an array of files */],
    totalSize: /* total size of the files */
}
```

thus `result.files` will be the array of files, and `result.totalSize` will be the total size.

Comment: would you please check the code i posted in "my attempts" section??

Comment: @LetsamrIt Your attemts make the object `accumulatedData` and `totalSize` gloabal which is not a good thing as you have to initialize them before each call to `getFiles`. Mine is taking care of that, you won't need to do that yourself.